# Having trouble on one of the raspi official projects "getting started with GUIs"

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

I have raspi 3, and working on "Getting started with GUIs". 
I am currently on this page (https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-guis/11) and having trouble at the line where it says "size = 40."
My IDE doesnt seem to recognize this line, which I mean the color of "40" doesnt change on my IDE. Matter of fact it shows an error after I press enter. I have installed and updated guizero and tkinter. Does anyone spot a problem and any solutions? Thanks.

Here below is the code btw.

```
from guizero import App, Text, TextBox, PushButton, Slider, Picture

def say_my_name():
    welcome_message.value = my_name.value

def change_text_size(slider_value):
    welcome_message.size = slider_value

app = App(title="Hello world")

welcome_message = Text(app, text="Welcome to my app", size=40, font="Times new roman", color="lightblue")
my_name = TextBox(app, width=30)
update_text = PushButton(app, command=say_my_name, text="Display my name")
text_size = Slider(app, command=change_text_size, start=10, end=80)
my_cat = Picture(app, image="cat.gif")

app.display()
```

Comment: `Matter of fact it shows an error after I press enter.` Please add the full error message to your question.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for the comment. Here is what I get.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    welcome_message = Text(app, text="Welcome to my app", size=40, font="Times new roman", color="lightblue")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/guizero/Text.py", line 12, in __init__
    tk = Label(master.tk, text=text, fg=utils.convert_color(color), bg=utils.convert_color(bg), font=(font, size))

Comment: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2763, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2296, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "label" command: application has been destroyed

Comment: Sorry I couldn't post it all at once, so I had to split it into 2.

Comment: As I said above it's best to add it to your question. Keeps stuff nicely together.

Comment: BTW: is this actually running on a Pi? Which OS?

Comment: Sorry Dirk I will try my best to post every information at the first place from next time.  This was on python IDE on mac OS. But I tried coding the same thing on raspi, and had the same message popped up. Do you have any clues?

Comment: `Do you have any clues?` Probably Python version or OS differences. Your code works on my Pi3 using Raspbian Stretch with default Python (3.5.x). So try again on your Pi...

Comment: It also runs on my Win10 PC using Python 3.6.5 and 3.7

Comment: Thanks for trying out the code on your PC and pi. When I bought my pi I installed NOOBS instead of Raspbian. Would that possibly be the reason?  Sorry I don't even recognize the difference in between them, but I just read noobs was recommended.

Comment: Noobs is just an OS installer. You're probably running Raspbian anyway.

Comment: I still don't get the right response from the IDE, but thank you so much for your help Dirk.

Comment: Do you mean 'IDLE'? IDLE could interfere with the script because it also uses tkinter. Try running it from the command line: `python3 scriptname,py'

Comment: Oh yes it was IDLE. Maybe that's the reason. I just tested the code on Mu-Editor, and it worked!   But I'm still curious why IDLE can't handle that code. May I ask what do you mean by interfere?

Comment: Idle uses tkinter, just like your script (through guizero). There are situations where there is some interference and apparently this is one of them.